# No Error with Cron but does not work

Tags: python, cron, python3, services

I have written a simple python script that sends notifications using Pushbullet. The command works perfectly in the terminal but does not work automatically. The syslog for Cron:

```
Nov 29 18:33:01 ubuntu CRON[4255]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/python3 IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1)

Nov 29 18:34:01 ubuntu CRON[4266]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1)

Nov 29 18:35:01 ubuntu CRON[4278]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1)

Nov 29 18:36:01 ubuntu CRON[4288]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/python3 /IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1)

Nov 29 18:37:01 ubuntu CRON[4297]: (root) CMD (usr/bin/python3 /IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1)

Nov 29 18:38:01 ubuntu CRON[4307]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Comment: If you want to know why, I suggest redirecting the output + error streams somewhere other than `/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is enviroment, cause cron does not have full root environment.

02 4 * * *      su - root -c '/IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1'

Use this cron entry to get full root environment. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved:)
I used sudo to open the corntab so the script was extcuted as root
I opened the crontab without sudo and added the same line on code

```
* * * * * python3 IdeaProjects/TradingScript/src/test.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

and it worked